# Send and receive text messages on computer using galaxy s2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sms, samsung-kies, pc-studio

I could use Nokia PC suite to receive and send SMS messages on my computer. But I could not find this feature in Samsung Kies.

How can I send and receive text messages on a PC using my Galaxy SII?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature isn't built into Android, but there is an app - [DeskSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.desktopsms), that allows you to do what you are asking.

It does, however, require the use of a browser plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at e.g. [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), which offers a little more than just SMS stuff:

[image: AirDroid]

This app establishes a service on your Android device, and you can connect to it via your favorite Web browser: Manage your files, contacts, SMS, and more. No special client-soft necessary on your PC (except for the Web browser).

If you want something more close to your Nokia Suite experience, take a look at [MyPhoneExplorer Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client):

[image: MyPhoneExplorer]

Here you need a special PC component (available for download on the developers homepage). But then you can synchronize lots of things with your PC (Windows only!), like e.g. your calendar with Outlook etc.

Comment: IIRC, this requires a Wi-Fi connection, which was the deal-breaker for me. I have no Wi-Fi at work!

Comment: That is correct: WiFi is required for all solutions I know. Your question did not include this restriction, so I was not aware it could be a deal-breaker. I'm not sure if any of these solutions would work via Tethering: Most recent devices (Android 2.3 and higher) also offer USB Tethering. It's just an idea how you *could* make them work for you.

Comment: There is a public beta which allows this to run on 2G/3G which is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm a bit late to the conversation. You could checkout PopMyPhone on the Google Play store. It sends/receives SMS through your email, and works if your phone only has3g. If you receive an SMS it will popup in your email system on your Desktop/Laptop/Tablet. You can reply and the SMS goes from your GS2. Search for PopMyPhone. There is nothing you need to install on your Desktop/Laptop/Tablet or anything else that can receive email.

Disclosure: I am affiliated to the people who develop PopMYPhone

Comment: Thanks, Andrew! Could you also provide a link (e.g. to the playstore page)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for a better solution.

But I recommend to try [mysms](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mysms.android.sms). It's the best that I found (and I tried Desksms, Airdroid, Browsertexting & Mightytext), and I'm using it for a while now. It replaces your stock SMS app on your Galaxy SII and lets you text from your PC at app.mysms.com. Messages are synced across your phone and computer. Until now the app has never let me down!

If you also use a tablet, they have also an app for it.